# Netflix website "server not found" firefox and chrome

Tags: netflix

I have recently become unable to access the Netflix website on either Firefox or Chrome. I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I do not have netflix-desktop installed, I am just trying to update my queue and such. I have clear history, cache and cookies to no avail.

This has been going on for several days, does not seem to be an issue on Windows PC at another location... I guess I need to try the Ubuntu laptop at some other wifi spot...

Anyone have recommendations to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I added google DNS to my network settings and it solved my problem.  Instructions can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/